# Wikipedia claims that number theorists tend to prefer $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. Is this actually true?

Tags: number-theory, convention

According to wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols):

> $\mathbb{N}$ means either $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$ or $\{ 1, 2, 3, ...\}.$
>
> The choice depends on the area of mathematics being studied; e.g.
>   number theorists prefer the latter; analysts, set theorists and
>   computer scientists prefer the former.

Is the claim that number theorists tend to prefer $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$ actually true?

Comment: Maybe one should take the (unreferenced) assertions on this WP page with a grain of salt? I believe French mathematicians consider that $\mathbb N$ contains $0$, whichever their specialization (probably because Bourbaki said so?). The WP page also declares that $\mathbb Z^*$ (which I know as the set of nonzero integer numbers) is the set of nonnegative integer numbers...

Comment: @Did, frankly I take *everything* with a grain of salt! Hence my bazillions of questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is any basis for that claim.

Sometimes it is better to include $0$, other times not. Either situation can arise in any branch of mathematics. It is a matter of notational convenience which varies with the case at hand.

As a general principle, any claim that is made about a large group of people which is not true for tautological reasons can safely be discarded as rubbish. Many number theorists disagree on what number theory even *is*, so you can be pretty sure that some of them like their zero to be natural, and some don't. Personally, I like my coffee with cream and a little bit of sugar (not too much).

Comment: ["In fact, Ribenboim (1996) states "Let $P$ be a set of natural numbers; whenever convenient, it may be assumed that $0 \in P$.""](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)